# How to make entity class and controller for biography backend using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, persistence

How would you make an entity class for the backend portion of a biography page (on a site). I am unsure how to approach something like this since there aren't specific things that need to be sent from the server. I have attached some code that I used for my entity class.

Does my entity class seem like the correct way to approach creating a backend for a biography page on a site using Spring Boot?

Entity Class

```java
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="BIOGRAPHY")
    public class Biography {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long sectionId;

        @Column(name = "section_title")
        private String titleSection;

        @Column(name = "section_text")
        private String textSection;




        public Long getSectionId() {
            return sectionId;
        }

        public String getTitleSection() {
            return titleSection;
        }

        public String getTextSection() {
            return textSection;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "EmployeeEntity [sectionId=" + sectionId + ", titleSection=" + titleSection +
                    ", textSection=" + textSection + "]";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you could do to implement a Spring controller that takes care of requests to the Biography entity.

1. Your Biography entity appears to be good
2. To work with it, you could take advantage of `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;`
   Namely:

```java
public interface BiographyRepository  extends CrudRepository <Biography, Long> {

}
```

3. Spring is pretty flexible and you can organize your code the way you like it. Here is just an example of how you could organize controller code:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping 
public class BiographyController {

  @Autowired
  private BiographyRepository biographyRepository;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/biography, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody
  Response create (HttpServletRequest request) {
    //read biography object from the request
    biographyRepository.save(biography);
  }

  //other methods...
}
```

Depending on what you need, a better practice could be working with the repository through a `@Service` in the Controller.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As a +1 to what Scary Wombat said in regards to my entity class, should my entity return the whole biography at once? Thank you for the advice Vic K. Do you and Scary Wombat have any other suggestions to improve my entity class?

Comment: @ScaryWombat gettextSection - I would consider it as misprint (which is already fixed, btw), that's a minor issue that they should catch themself. As for the setters - it's actually up to their needs. If they need only reading the biography, setters may not be needed - the usage contexts is not described in the original question, so it's not necessarily a wrong thing.

Comment: @VicK Thanks for setting me straight about the `setters`

Comment: What purpose would setters serve in this case for the biography or any biography page in general?

Comment: so in the example in my answer I showed only one method: create. If this is something useful in your usecase, then you would need setters, when you parse the incoming request into the Biography object. There are other methods possible, like read, delete, update. If you need just read - you don't need setters

Comment: @ScaryWombat sure:)

Comment: This was helpful, so thank you. I have accepted the answer but my upvote isn't shown since I haven't obtained 15 rep yet. Thank you!